# open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: unknown when running shell script from Java program

Tags: java, macos, shell, sh, tmux

I had a Java program running a shell script with a Process, but for some reason when I try to run it it throws an error `open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: unknown`. From other SO questions, I think this is a tmux problem, but I'm not really sure how to solve it. Here's the code calling the script:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/project/start.sh");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("output: ");
String s;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And here's the shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh
ssh -tt -i ~/.ssh/ssh-key.key opc@___._.___.___ tmux attach -d << END 
    ./run.sh 
END
exit 0
```

I have tried running the script from terminal, and it works from the terminal but it doesn't work when I run the Java program.

Comment: Which of the statements produces the error message exactly? And: It's just this message printed to stderr which you see, not an exception? I'm asking because I don't see anything in your code which would actually need a terminal, so I suspect that the error comes from inside `start.sh`.

Comment: The shell doesn't care whether you have a terminal or not, but you're probably running a command from the shell which does. Some `curses` programs like `top` have an option to turn off the interactive features so you can run them programmatically; others will require hideous workarounds like running under a `pty`. But your question lacks crucial information, so it's hard to provide any specific advice.

Comment: If `start.sh` tries to start up `tmux`, you probably have a massive [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); just don't do that. To run processes in parallel programmatically, just start them as individual subprocesses from your program.

Comment: Yeah sorry I completely forgot to post the sh file, I'll do it right now

Comment: @tripleee I needed to ssh into a server and then start a script, but since just starting it in ssh ends the process when I exit the session, and also since I needed to easily go back to the same thread I needed tmux or screen.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `ssh -tt -i ~/.ssh/ssh-key.key opc@___._.___.___ tmux send-keys './run' C-m` instead? That avoids attempting to attach to the session with its interactive controls, which is your problem here.

Comment: More fundamentally, refactoring your work flow to simply `nohup run.sh` on the remote server with output to a file is almost always a better solution if you don't specifically need to interact with `run.sh` subsequently.

Comment: That command was actually perfect and worked exactly as I needed it, thank you so much! I did need to interact with it afterward on other computers so I don't think nohup will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attaching to an interactive `tmux` session, where you need to have a terminal which supports cursor movement codes etc.

The easy workaround is to not attach; just submit the command you want to run into the session.

```
ssh -tt -i ~/.ssh/ssh-key.key opc@___._.___.___ tmux send-keys './run' C-m
```

This obviously requires that whatever is running inside the remote `tmux` session is in a state where you can submit a shell command, i.e. at a shell prompt or similar. For robustness you might want to take additional measures to make sure this is always the case, or refactor your solution to avoid running inside `tmux` e.g. by having the command redirect its output to a file where you can examine it from any terminal at any time (though this assumes you don't also need to interact with it subsequently).